# How to add a new property in the route object of the JSS Layout Service?

Tags: jss, layout-service

By default, the Layout Service provides the layout information as `layoutId` in the route object. Although it is difficult to make a connection with this information in other applications since the id is automatically generated and not under the user control, unlike the Layout Name that is determined by the user.

It seems I can easily add the `layoutName` property in the context object but I prefer adding it in the **route object** of the layout service.

Is there a resource where I can find instructions on how to add a new property in the route object of the JSS Layout Service?

Comment: So, you want to extend the Layout Service Context for the route node? And not create it under a new section?

Comment: Hi @HishaamNamooya, yes I'd like to keep it in the route node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have performed an investigation on how Sitecore adds the values to the route. As of now, I've found 2 ways of adding custom data to the `route` node:

1. Extend the `GetJsLayoutRenderer` and override the `RenderItem`
2. Change the serialization transformer.

For your case, the quickest way is to use the second option. The first one will require more customization on the model being used etc. So, for the second option, you need to override the current implementation of the `LayoutTransformer` found at the namespace `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Serialization.LayoutTransformer` in the assembly `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine`.

The implementation is as follows:

```
using System.Dynamic;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Serialization;
using Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering;

public class CustomLayoutTransformer : LayoutTransformer
{
    public CustomLayoutTransformer(IPlaceholderTransformer placeholderTransformer) : base(placeholderTransformer)
    {
    }

    public override dynamic Transform(RenderedItem rendered)
    {
        var route = ((rendered.Name == null) ? null : new
        {
            name = rendered.Name,
            displayName = rendered.DisplayName,
            fields = rendered.Fields,
            databaseName = rendered.DatabaseName,
            deviceId = rendered.DeviceId,
            itemId = rendered.ItemId,
            itemLanguage = rendered.ItemLanguage,
            itemVersion = rendered.ItemVersion,
            layoutId = rendered.LayoutId,
            layoutName = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID(rendered.LayoutId))?.Name,
            templateId = rendered.TemplateId,
            templateName = rendered.TemplateName,
            placeholders = PlaceholderTransformer.TransformPlaceholders(rendered.Placeholders)
        });

        dynamic val = new ExpandoObject();

        val.sitecore = new
        {
            context = rendered.Context,
            route = route
        };
        return val;
    }
}
```

You will notice that I have added a property in the route model named `layoutName` and then I've used the `rendered.LayoutId` to retrieve the layout item name.

Once you have the code above implemented, you need to patch the current `LayoutTransformer` with the new one. An example of the patch config is provided below

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <layoutService>
      <configurations>
        <config name="jss">
          <serialization type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.SerializationConfiguration, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine">
            <transformer type="Sitecore.Module.Checklist.Pipelines.CustomLayoutTransformer, Sitecore.Module.Checklist" patch:instead="transformer[@type='Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Serialization.LayoutTransformer, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine']" resolve="true" />
          </serialization>
        </config>
      </configurations>
    </layoutService>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Below is a screenshot of the result

[image]

Now, I will investigate a bit more on how to perform the first implementation and document it. I will share the link here once done.

Comment: This works! Thanks @Hishaam Namooya